# How do I fetch data from multiple documents in a Firebase collection

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'm getting the user's location then using that location to fetch documents containing that location then displaying the data within the documents on the page.
The structure of my `Firebase Database` is `/posts/{userId}/userPosts/{postId}`. I want it to search through all the posts (meaning through all the different `postId`s).

```
Future<void> initState() {
    super.initState();
    getListings();
  }

  getListings() async {
    placemark = await getUserLocation();
    getLocationListings(placemark);
  }

  getLocationListings(placemark) async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts')
        // .doc(userId)
        // .collection('userPosts')
        .where('location', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: placemark.locality)
        .get();
    setState(() {
      posts = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => Post.fromDocument(doc)).toList();
      isLoading = false;
    });
    // print(placemark.locality);
  }
```

When I run the code as it is (`.doc(userId)` and `.collection('userPosts')` commented out), the list `List<Post> posts = [];` remains empty. However, when I uncomment them and provide a `userId`, I get all the documents containing `placemark.locality`. How can I go round this?
[image]

Comment: Please share a screenshot of your db structure. What is the locality? Are you trying to use isEqualTo?

Comment: I've updated it in the question.

Comment: @Dharmaraj The locality in my case is Nairobi, and there are several documents with location set as Nairobi. `isEqualTo` still brings no results.

Comment: I can't see the data in the screenshot. The queries are case sensitive. Are you sure the case it correct and is exactly that one name ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I've updated it. Yeah, the query matches the field. The location field was actually updated using a similar code.

Comment: The `placemark.locality` should be exactly as in the database if you are using isEqualTo